# Does making a correction in the rollback block affect the checksum of a liquibase changeset?

Tags: liquibase

Minor typos were discovered, eg.:

```
    <rollback>
        <delete tableName="velocity_template">
            <where>id in ("from-address.vm", "myco.from-address.vm")</where>
        </delete>
    </rollback>
```

to

```
    <rollback>
        <delete tableName="velocity_template">
            <where>id in ('from-address.vm', 'myco.from-address.vm')  </where>
        </delete>
    </rollback>
```

Can these be corrected without the need to rollback and re-apply the changeset?

The docs here do not specifically say anything about the rollback block, one way or another:  http://www.liquibase.org/2009/03/what-effects-changeset-checksums.html

My local testing suggests that the rollback block is not a part of the checksum calculation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rollback blocks are not included in the checksum, see:

http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/fixing-and-enforcing-liquibase-rollbacks

But even if they were, you could have used "validCheckSum" sub-tag, which is a generic way to update the changeset post-factum, w/o making it break on databases on which it has already been applied.

Comment: the documentation link is no more valid. I didn't find this answer in the new liquibase documentation.

Comment: May be new link  refers to this, https://forum.liquibase.org/t/fixing-and-enforcing-liquibase-rollbacks/1123/4