# Do all the parts of a given changeset contribute to the corresponding MD5 checksum value in the databasechangelog table, in the Liquibase?

Tags: liquibase

I know, that it is a bad idea to change changeset that has already been applied to the database, as the MD5 checksum of a changeset is changing and Liquibase will not be able to validate it.

However, I've spotted one very interesting (to me, at least) behaviour.

If I have a changeset, that I have *already applied*:

```xml
<changeSet id="Drop lastname column" author="Giorgi Tsiklauri">
    <dropColumn tableName="profiles" columnName="lastname">
    </dropColumn>

    <rollback>
        <addColumn tableName="profiles">
            <column name="lastname" type="varchar(100)"/>
        </addColumn>

        <update tableName="profiles">
            <column name="lastname" value="Default Lastname"/>
            <where>lastname is null</where>
        </update>

        <addNotNullConstraint tableName="profiles" columnName="lastname" columnDataType="varchar(100)"/>

    </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

its respective record is inserted into `databasechangelog` table (with its MD5 checksum).

Now, if I modify this changeset (e.g. I set `columnDataType="char(1)"`), this **must** change the MD5 value and make this changeset invalid, but it does **not** make it invalid and following `rollbackCount 1` works just fine.

I am really confused. It's either (1) not everything of a changeset is part of its MD5 checksum, or (2) there is a bug in Liquibase.

Any clarification?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Liquibase's [description](https://www.liquibase.com/blog/what-affects-changeset-checksums) of checksum calculation process is rather vague.

> However, not every change to a changeset impacts the checksum. Here
> are some examples:
>
> Reformatting whitespace and linebreaks (except
> within SQL statements)
>
> Changing preconditions
>
> Changing contexts
> Changing labels
>
> Adding validCheckSum settings
>
> Changing comments (via
> native xml/yaml comments or using the comment tag)

`<rollback>` is not part of a checksum as well. So that's why you don't see checksum validation errors.

**Update**

Some semantics and guesses:

Checksums are used to detect changes in "changes" (e.g. useful payload) of a changeSet. `rollback` does not bring any "changes" to the database schema during changeSet execution. Therefore they are not included in checksum calculation.

Some facts:

I couldn't find any documented proof that `rollback` is (or not) a part of a checksum. It's more than a theory, confirmed by experiment. It could be a bug though. You can always review the [source code](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase).

You may refer to this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40348856/does-making-a-correction-in-the-rollback-block-affect-the-checksum-of-a-liquibas) as well.

Comment: So, on one side we should never change changesets as they change (not always, apparently) checksums; and on the other side, first statement is not quite true..? but where is `<rollback>` mentioned, as it's not a part of checksum calculation? I can't find that on the page you've linked.

Comment: Yes, changeSets are supposed to be 'forward only' thing. If you need to make some changes, you write a new changeSet. Regarding the rest - generally you're right. I've updated my answer